# Tumblelog Application with Flask and MongoEngine example does not work - Complete Novice

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

The [Tumblelog app](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/#django) on the MongoDB site does not work .

I've followed the example absolutely and I get a 404 error when I run it in my local host. I'm using Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) with pyDev on Ubuntu 12.0.4.

I'm not sure if it's because of the `register_blueprints`, which I included in the `__init__.py`

I did it like this as in the tutorial:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGODB_DB"] = "my_tumble_log"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "KeepThisS3cr3t"

db = MongoEngine(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


    def register_blueprints(app):
    # Prevents circular imports
        from tumblelog.views import posts
        app.register_blueprint(posts)
    register_blueprints(app)
```

Otherwise I have followed the tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`register_blueprints` is never called - `app.run` blocks until you kill the script (at which point there is no point to adding routes).

Change the order and everything will run:

```
def register_blueprints(app):
# Prevents circular imports
    from tumblelog.views import posts
    app.register_blueprint(posts)

register_blueprints(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`regist_blueprints` is not actually preventing circular imports - the pattern to avoid circular imports is to create the `app` in a different file and import both `app` and `blueprint` into a third file to run everything:

```
#  application.py
from flask import Flask  # etc.

app = Flask("your_package_name")
```

```
# tumblelog/views.py
from flask import Blueprint, current_app  # etc.

posts = Blueprint("tumblelog")

@posts.route("/")
def index():
    # use current_app rather than app here
```

```
# run_server.py (use the same pattern for .wsgi files)
from application import app
from tumblelog.views import posts

app.register_blueprint(posts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I've changed the order as you said and it seems to work fine now. Many thanks